# Starting Erlang service at boot time (using Relx for creating release)

Tags: erlang, relx

I have a server written in Erlang, compiled with Rebar, and I make a release with Relx. Starts nicely with

```
/root/rel/share3/bin/share3 start
```

The next step is to start when the server boots.

I have tried different approaches, the last one is using the /etc/init.d/skeleton where I changed the following

```
NAME=share3
DAEMON=/root/rel/share3/bin/share3
DAEMON_ARGS="$1"
```

After that, I run update-rc.d, but I have not gotten it too work. (Ubuntu 14.04)

The service runs until the machine reboots, and I need to login and start it again.

For Windows, it is really elegant, since it can create the Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) as init system, so you could try something like that:

```
description "Start my awesome service"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /root/rel/share3/bin/share3
```

You have to place this script in `/etc/init/` directory with '.conf' extension like '/etc/init/share3.coinf'. To start it invoke `sudo start share3`.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I solved it!

I have told to relx to place the result at /home/mattias/rel. The script from relx is /home/mattias/rel/share3/bin/share3

Replace the row

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$0")"
```

by (you need to fix the path /home/mattias/rel)

```
HOME=/home/mattias
export HOME
SCRIPT_DIR="/home/mattias/rel/share3/bin"
```

Copy the file to /etc/init.d/share3 using

```
sudo cp ~/rel/share3/bin/share3 /etc/init.d/
```

Test that it works using

```
/etc/init.d/share3 start
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/share3 stop
```

In order to make it start at boot, install sysv-rc-conf

```
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

Enable boot at start using

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf share3 on
```

and disable

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf share3 off
```

Alternatives are welcome.